# (C++) What can I do with the "operator" function?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, using

I saw some code of the "operator" type in the internet with some examples:

```
//Overloaded operators
    int& operator[](int) const; //function type: int& because returns a[i] (or &a[i])
    const Vector& operator++();
    const Vector& operator--();
    const bool operator==(Vector&) const;
    Vector& operator=(const Vector&); //COPY ASSIGNMENT - rule of 3
    Vector& operator+=(const Vector&); //a Vector, += a vector (since its IN the vector class)
    const Vector operator+(const Vector&); //adds values of two equal sized vectors
    const Vector& operator+(int);       //deals with adding a single int (essentially .pushBack(int))
```

I want to be able being sure to know what this "operator" function can do, but it's not easy to search for it.

Does someone know what "operator" is?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Search online for "operator overloading in c++".

Comment: You might want to read a modern book on C++. Any good book should cover operator overloading and what they are used for.

Comment: The term you need to search for is "operator overload".

Comment: Probably this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you.